# How to release two-way communication of backend servers in web development?

Tags: node.js, laravel, websocket, redis, rabbitmq

(help to design the functionality and choose the right technologies for my personal development )

Describing the task:

the main server receives a file from the site, then validates it and pulls several files from it.

All files are saved on disk and in the data base with user id.

Each file is checked for the amount of work.

The main server checks connections to the servers in the database. Servers that answer that they are active - it takes this number, for example 7 servers.

For example, we have 100% of work and it is divided into 7 servers and it is 14%.

The same file is sent to each server.

So the first server will go from zero to 14%.

the third one will go from 15% to 28% percent.

Each one will take a different part of it to work.

and so on.

What are the actual questions !

The user needs to throw

1. if one server finishes working with the file before the others. the other servers should stop, and the user should throw a message - the work on the first file is completed.
2. when all pieces of the file have been worked through by all servers and work on the file is not successful - then we tell the user that it is not successful.
3. when the user himself presses the button - to find out the percentage of completion

Actually the main question of all this, I do not know how to connect the servers.

1. I need the main one to be able to communicate with other servers.
2. Other servers can communicate with the main server and among themselves.

If they don't need to communicate with each other, I would just make requests through gazl or throw a webhook.

I was also looking at rabbitmq queues, but with that I also came to a trivial question - how can a task be set to complete if it is only completed when all servers have finished.

Websockets doesn't fit here either. Since it is usually a client and a server. And I have a main backend server and a bunch of other backend servers.

In general, there are a lot of questions, guys, help me

I was looking towards radis, rabbitmq, websokets